# How can I find X_train indexes in the main dataset?

Tags: python, indexing, jupyter-notebook

We can split the dataset to X_train, y_train by Sklearn function in Python.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, shuffle=True, test_size=0.3)
```

My question is: how can we find the X_train or y_train indexes in our data set?

suppose we found the prediction by

```
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

Also, how can we find the indexes for prediction?

I am asking because I would like to see each row's values when I get inaccurate results.

In other words, data is the main dataset and *subset* is data's subset

data = array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
subest = array([ 2, 4, 5, 6])

How can I find the subset's index in data?

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), it is a quick application of `sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit, train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1, test_size=1)
x_train
array([[2, 3],
       [8, 9],
       [0, 1],
       [6, 7]])
```

This is yield by the split sets of indices from `ShuffleSplit`:

```
train_ind, test_ind = next(ShuffleSplit(random_state=1).split(X, y))
X[train_ind]
array([[2, 3],
       [8, 9],
       [0, 1],
       [6, 7]])
```

So you can use `train_ind` and/or `test_ind` made by `ShuffleSplit` and it will be just same as using `train_test_split`

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I have learned new things. But I didn't get my answer. what if we need to find a subset's indexes? How can we find the subset's (example above) indexes? I know numpy.where has almost the same function but it is for a conditional situation. I am looking for something to consider all values in the subset